# how to detect if a url contains a word in webview

Tags: android, webview

I am trying to call `onPageStarted` to make my button invisible when a certain page loads. However, it never gets called, how do i fix this?

```
private class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient { // handle URLs in
                                                    // webview only
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
    view.loadUrl(url);
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onPageStarted(WebView view, String url, Bitmap favicon)
{
    if (url.contains("clipconvertor")) {
        findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }

}
```

}

Comment: I don't see a question here.

Comment: i edited the question @DougStevenson

Comment: The word you mentioned " clipconvertor " present in the url or present in the contents and pages where the url is loaded.

Comment: Why are you overriding shouldOverrideUrlLoading like that?  Do you know what this does?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below your Webview.loadUrl call have your check

i.e

```
    if (url.contains("clipconvertor")) {
    findViewById(R.id.button1).setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

also in shouldOverrideUrlLoading method  below view.loadUrl(url); have the above check. It should work.

And if you want your above implementation to work make sure you are using only one instance of your webview client. Calling setWebViewClient(new MyWebViewClient()) will override instance.(In case you have done this)

Comment: Am sorry about that.

Comment: It didn't work, but i'm choosing this answer anyway.